# Error on product update via API

Tags: product, error, api, session, enterprise-1.13

We are getting the following error on updating products via the Magento API.

```
Error message
Uncaught Exception: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element' is not allowed' in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php:97
```

I have cleared all session data and even turned off cron, but the issue still happens. I have profiled the normal product save and have not found any issues.

**EDIT:** Problem is happening only on update and appears to be related to an attribute. We are trying to debug this

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post the product info that you're updating when you get the error?

Comment: It happens on any product, but I will get more details

Comment: Apparently you are adding to the session an instance of `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element` and when magento tries to write it to the disk it fails because it cannot be serialized. Now why would you add a config element model to the session? Any extensions? Any special attribute?

Comment: There is a module calle Insync (encrypted) and we don't have access to this. They are accessing the product update through the API. We are trying to narrow it down to one product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a product with data in an attribute that was not escaped correctly in the Insync module. The client updated the data and now things are working correctly.